Sequalize associating one model on an RDS database and an Aurora database
I tried to associate a model with 2 different databases that have this same table, one in an aurora db and another in a RDS db using sequalize. They have a different schema name but the same table name: organization. How do I associate a model with 2 other models in different databases?
The connection works when I only associate the organization model with one other model, but errors when I associate with 2 models.
This is the error I am seeing:
msg":"Database connection init appears to have failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')\n    at new HasMany  at Function.hasMany

I initialized each database. I only included a snippet of the connection set up for the database that initializes and associates the models. For example:
public async initialize(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.sequelize) {
      this.log.info("Database already initialized");
      return;
    }
this.sequelize = new Sequelize(null, null, null, {
        dialect: "postgres",
        schema: process.env.AURORA_DB_SCHEMA,
        define: {
          timestamps: true,
          underscored: true
        },

      Organization.initialize(this.sequelize);
      Record.initialize(this.sequelize);
      Organization.associate();
      Record.associate();
 } catch (e) {
      this.log.error(`Aurora initialization went wrong: ${e.stack}.`);
    }
      


I used the same set up for connecting the RDS db:
public async initialize(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.sequelize) {
      this.log.info("Database already initialized");
      return;
    }
this.sequelize = new Sequelize(null, null, null, {
        dialect: "postgres",
        schema: process.env.RDS_DB_SCHEMA,
        define: {
          timestamps: true,
          underscored: true
        },

      Organization.initialize(this.sequelize);
      Record.initialize(this.sequelize);
      Organization.associate();
      Record.associate();
 } catch (e) {
      this.log.error(`RDS initialization went wrong: ${e.stack}.`);
    }
      


Then I have the tables.
Log Table
import {
  Model,
  InferAttributes,
  InferCreationAttributes,
  DataTypes,
  CreationOptional,
  Sequelize,
  BOOLEAN,
  DATE,
  literal
} from "sequelize";
import {Organization } from "./organization";
export class Log extends Model<
  InferAttributes<Log>,
  InferCreationAttributes<Log>
> {
  
  declare readonly id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare date: any;
  declare name: string;
  declare index: string;

  public static initialize(sequelize: Sequelize): void {
    Log.init(
      {
        id: {
          allowNull: false,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        date: {
          type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
          allowNull: false
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false
        },
        index: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false
        },
      {
        sequelize: sequelize,
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false,
        modelName: "log",
        }
      }
    );
  }
  public static associate(): void {
    Log.belongsTo(Organization),
      {
        foreignKey: "name",
        targetKey: "name",
        as: "Or"
      };
  }
}


Tree Table
import {
  Model,
  InferAttributes,
  InferCreationAttributes,
  DataTypes,
  CreationOptional,
  Sequelize,
  BOOLEAN,
  DATE,
  literal
} from "sequelize";
import {Organization } from "./organization";
export class Tree extends Model<
  InferAttributes<Tree>,
  InferCreationAttributes<Tree>
> {
  
  declare readonly id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare startDate: any;
  declare name: string;
  declare alert: string;

  public static initialize(sequelize: Sequelize): void {
    Tree.init(
      {
        id: {
          allowNull: false,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        startDate: {
          type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
          allowNull: false
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false
        },
        alert: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false
        },
      {
        sequelize: sequelize,
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false,
        modelName: "tree",
        }
      }
    );
  }
  public static associate(): void {
   Tree.belongsTo(Organization),
      {
        foreignKey: "name",
        targetKey: "name",
        as: "Org"
      };
  }
}


I tried associating this model, Organization, with both the Tree(RDS db) and Log(Aurora db) models using sequalize.
import {
  Sequelize,
  Model,
  InferAttributes,
  InferCreationAttributes,
  DataTypes,
  CreationOptional
} from "sequelize";
import { Log } from "./log";
import { Tree } from "./tree";

export class Organization extends Model<
  InferAttributes<Organization>,
  InferCreationAttributes<Organization>
> {
  declare readonly id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare createdAt: any;
  declare updatedAt: any;
  declare subdivision: string;
  declare name: string;
  declare active: boolean;

  public static initialize(sequelize: Sequelize): void {
     Organization.init(
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: false,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
        },
        createdAt: { type: DataTypes.TIME, allowNull: true },
        updatedAt: { type: DataTypes.TIME, allowNull: true },
        subdivision: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        active: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false }
      },
      {
        sequelize: sequelize,
        modelName: "organizations",
        defaultScope: {
          where: {
            active: true
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }

  public static associate(): void {
    Organization.hasMany(Log, { foreignKey: "name", sourceKey: "name" });
    Organization.hasMany(Tree, { foreignKey: "name", sourceKey: "name" });
  }
}


AFAIK Sequelize like many other ORMs can make to work models with each other only from the same DB
